# Stream context in PHP - what is it?

Tags: php, stream

I have searched for hours and I cannot figure out what a 'stream context' in PHP is. I'm trying to use an API and it involves using this 'stream context'.

The documentation says:

> A context is a set of parameters and wrapper specific options which modify or enhance the behavior of a stream.

1. A parameter of what?
2. What is meant by an option being 'specific to a wrapper'?
3. What stream?

Here is the code I'm talking about:

```
// Encode the credentials and create the stream context.
$auth = base64_encode("$acctKey:$acctKey");
$data = array(
'http' => array(
'request_fulluri' => true,
// ignore_errors can help debug – remove for production. This option added in PHP 5.2.10
'ignore_errors' => true,
'header' => "Authorization: Basic $auth")
);
$context = stream_context_create($data);
// Get the response from Bing.
$response = file_get_contents($requestUri, 0, $context);
```

Comment: You find some explanation here: http://php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php and the available options in http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.php

Comment: Yes I read it and I quoted it in the opening post. It doesn't explain these concepts and that includes both of those links.

Comment: "streams" in PHP are virtual files. Any file API data reading that doesn't originate in a physical file on disk comes from a network connection or virtual resource. And streams are simply those network sources mapped onto filehandles.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me a bit but I don't get how that makes the file 'virtual' and what do you mean the network sources are mapped onto filehandles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. A parameter of the context that modifies the properties of the stream.
2. The options are specific to whatever wrapper the stream is using. Examples of these include files, all the different `php://` URIs, the HTTP wrapper (like when you do `file_get_contents('http://example.com')` — it’s not the same thing as `file_get_contents('some-file.txt')`)
3. Any stream!

In this case, the stream context is passed to `file_get_contents` to tell it to send that authorization header and those options to the wrapper that allows `file_get_contents` to get contents from HTTP URLs.

You can find a list of the HTTP context options [on the PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

Comment: But what is the stream here and how is it a 'stream'? What is a context and what is the 'context' that the parameter modifies?

Comment: @user2537201 Have you read the documentation? http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/stream.contexts.php

Comment: @user2537201: The stream here is the HTTP stream used to request whatever URL you pass `file_get_contents`. The context is what holds the parameters to change how the stream behaves. It’s just a set of properties for the stream.

Comment: @hek2mgl yes in fact I quoted that very page

Comment: @minitech What do you mean by the HTTP stream though?

Comment: Like how is it a "stream"?

Comment: @user2537201: `fopen('hello.txt')` and you have a file stream. `fopen('http://example.com/')` and you have an HTTP stream. (This is not entirely accurate but is probably close enough.) `file_get_contents` itself is not a stream, but it uses a stream and so you can give it a stream context.

Comment: I kind of get it better now, thanks, but isn't fopen example.com just opening a file on example.com and is therefore a file stream?

Comment: Also, I assume fopen creates an actual stream for the file hello.txt. So data can be taken from this stream and data added to it. I remember in C you had the input/output stream and you created file streams. But where is the stream here? Was it created? Where is it and how does it work?

Comment: Why is the address called a stream?

Comment: @user2537201: No, it’s not just opening a file. It’s opening a URL, but you don’t get to see that because PHP handles it in the background, using a wrapper. I’m not sure what you mean with the address being called a stream; you create a stream from the address. And `fopen` may or may not create an actual stream for a file; I’m not familiar with the PHP internals *that* intimately :) But yes, opening `php://stdin` would be a stream handled by PHP. Yes, it would be created.

Comment: @minitech What do you mean 'opening a URL'? Isn't that pointing to a file on a server? Also, by creating a stream, do you mean creating a stream that is just a container for all the text in what is at that url?

Comment: @user2537201: A stream is a thing that you can either add things to or take things from in order, or both. Opening a URL is not the same thing as pointing to a file on a server; a URL can point to anything and a server can serve anything. Key differences here are: a) the response stream is read-only b) it’s actually a stream, so you can’t seek back and forth through it

Comment: @user2537201: So no, it’s not just a container for the text. It’s actually a thing that receives bytes over TCP, parses them as HTTP, and pushes the content out in a stream.

Answer (score 9):

It took me a while to understand the stream contexts options and wrappers of PHP. I wrote an article about what helped me finally wrap my brain around [how to understand PHP stream contexts options and wrappers](https://www.paulleasure.com/drupal-6-drupal-7/how-to-understand-php-stream-wrapper-context-and-options/). I hope it helps.

> To properly handle whatever is coming down the line (streamed data), you will need the appropriate code to handle the different kinds of items being passed (data types). The tools for handling each different kind of data type are the “parameters”.
>
> The “context” is determined by what is being pass along (streamed). So for different “contexts” (kinds of items) being “streamed” (passed along) the “parameters” (required tools for handling) the “data type” (kind of item) will change.
>
> The term context simply makes reference to the fact that for different data types the situation is unique with its own required parameters.
>
> The PHP stream wrapper would require a context in order to know which parameters are needed to handle the data type.

Comment: (FYI, I deleted my outdated comment on the URL change.)

Comment: Very helpful.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. http, request_fulluri, ignore_errors, header are all parameters.
   They change the way the function (file_get_contents in this case) works.
2. An option that is specific to a wrapper is something like 'http' --
   you wouldn't use that on a filesystem file stream since it's not applicable.
3. The stream is the transfer of data itself which occurs when file_get_contents opens the connection, transfers everything, etc...

Comment: Thanks but I still don't get #3. First of all, what do you mean by the stream 'is' the transfer of data. What part of the transfer of data is the stream? Second, what do you mean by the data 'itself'?

Comment: PHP uses wrappers to handle various protocol operations (whether it be file, http, ftp, etc). PHPs stream objects are essentially the underlying code that access various protocols (http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.stream.php).

The stream (itself was irrelevant) is essentially the conduit that the data flows from point A to point B (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_stream). Specifically in this case it is from point A to Bing via HTTP.