# Load HTML file and force UTF8 with PHP

Tags: php, html, utf-8, file-get-contents

I am accessing an external URL to get a specific content of it with xPath.

I tried several different ways to achieve this, but all of them end up presenting a little problem. After a big research, I do it this way:

I create a [stream context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394619/stream-context-in-php-what-is-it) to open the file with the right headers: utf-8

```
$opts=array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0'));
$context=stream_context_create($opts);
$html=file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
```

Then, inside my class, where I created a DOMDocument object, I load the fetched HTML string, as follows:

```
$this->dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

It works fine in almost every case, but it will sometimes strip away complex characters, like á, ó, ç, etc..

**Example**: "*gobierno marroquí para*" turns into "*gobierno marroqu para*"

I also tried loading my HTML with a plain text prefix `<?xml encoding...` and it works fine, but then I have issues with further HTMLPurifier operations.

Any kind of information is appreciated, I am not looking for somebody to do this task for me, but for the right and most efficient way. I need to understand it all so i can work with it.

Peace.

Comment: Do you have the mbstring php extension installed?

Comment: Can you try the following after `file_get_contents` . ------- `$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($html, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));` .

Comment: @DavidDomain It works like a charm now. So, what I am doing is: "Load HTML", "Convert it into UTF-8, from UTF-8 or ISO88591", "Load the string into the PHP OBJECT". But.... what I do not get is the last part. Why do I need to convert it into "HTML-ENTITIES", why can I not just open it in UTF-8? (I tried and it results in messed up characters)

Comment: You have non utf-8 encoded characters in the loaded file they need to be converted to display correct.